# mysql regexp_replace with update

Tags: mysql, regexp-replace

I just upgraded MySQL to 8.0.11 to be able to use the regexp_replace.  It works fine in a select statement, but when I use the same in an update, I get strange results.  Here is a simplified example: if I have a field with "567890", and I updated it with this:

```
update test set field = regexp_replace(field, '[7]', 'z')
```

instead of "56z890", the field value is set to "56".

This must be a bug, but in the meantime, are there any workarounds to get it to work as expected?  Thanks.

Comment: maybe it's a stored function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-procedure.html

Comment: Is the field numeric maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a bug of the [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) function. In MariaDB it works as expected, see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=76eb4b7e5348627d9b378f3166f9527b).

<strike>I'll try to report the bug in [bugs.mysql.com](https://bugs.mysql.com/).</strike> Bug was already reported, [Bug #90803 regexp_replace accumulating result](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90803) and [Bug #90870 REGEXP_REPLACE truncate UPDATE](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90870).

A workaround is:

```sql
UPDATE `test`
SET `field` = CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(`field`, '[7]', 'z') AS CHAR);
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6576d8d81b9841b7dfc8ab08839b5ec6).

Comment: Yes, that workaround did fix it for a replace of one record.  Then I tested a SELECT over a set of records, and the output is somehow adding the results of one record to the results of the next record.  So by the end it is one concatenation of all the previous records.  Doing it with an actual update could be disastrous, so I think I'll wait until the next revision comes out.  Thanks again.

Comment: Bug #90803 describes the second issue I found, in my previous comment.  But this seems separate from my original issue, where a replace on a single row is truncating the result.

Comment: @RayGurganus: New bug reported, [Bug #90870](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=90870). See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **Apache Version(PHP) 5.6** and **MySQL version 10.1.25-Maria DB** Localhost Server.

I've tried with the following query,

```
UPDATE `table_name` 
SET         
    column_name = REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name,regex_pattern_to_find,replaceable_text)
WHERE
    column_name RLIKE 'regex_pattern_to_find'
```

It was working fine for me. Hope this helps.

Comment: Why filter using where condition when regexp_replace already replace the targeted pattern ? Some kind of security ?

Comment: @Heraknos If you don't add the where condition, the query will check all the rows and update if the regex condition is matched. 

It'll consume more time when you've more rows, so we just have to filter the rows first and then replace the column further. Hope it helps ;)